# Usar componentes de JavaFX en un JFrame de Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx

Quiero usar componentes de JavaFx dentro de un `JFrame` de Java Swing. La aplicación es una `JFrame` donde hay uno botón que lanza otro `JFrame`, en el que colocó un `JFXPanel` para mostrar otros componentes de JavaFX.

Entonces, tengo esta clase donde se encuentra `main()`:

```
package JavaGUIPackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class EjemploJavaGUI extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel lblTitle;
    private final JButton btnJFX;
    private final LanzarVentana lanzarVentana;

    public EjemploJavaGUI() {
        setTitle("Ejemplos de GUI ");
        setSize(400, 190);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        lanzarVentana = new LanzarVentana();

        this.lblTitle = new JLabel("Seleccione un Framework");
        this.lblTitle.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 20);
        getContentPane().add(this.lblTitle);

        this.btnJFX = new JButton("JavaFX");
        this.btnJFX.setBounds(20 + 100 + 20, 70, 100, 40);
        this.btnJFX.addActionListener(lanzarVentana);
        getContentPane().add(this.btnJFX);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public class LanzarVentana implements ActionListener {
        
        private String botonPresionado;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            this.botonPresionado = e.getActionCommand();

            switch(this.botonPresionado) {
                case "JavaFX" -> JFXFramework.prender();
            }
        }  
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EjemploJavaGUI ejemplo= new EjemploJavaGUI();
        ejemplo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

La clase `JFXFramework` la tomé de la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm). Simplemente quité la clase `main()` para poder llamarla desde la clase principal:

```
package JavaGUIPackage;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFXFramework {
    
    public JFXFramework() {}
    
    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
       });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        Group  root  =  new  Group();
        Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        Text  text  =  new  Text();
        
        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");

        root.getChildren().add(text);

        return (scene);
    }
    
    public static void prender() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El programa se compila sin errores, pero al oprimir el botón, aparece este error:

```
mar. 21, 2021 1:25:22 P. M. com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @5c7ea94e'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:273)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Los archivos jar de javafx los coloqué en una carpeta junto a src en el proyecto de netbeans, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego los agregué a la librería del proyecto, quedando de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué debo modificar para mostrar mi programa correctamente?

Comment: Estás usando los JMods, el SDK o los JARs de JavaFX?

Comment: Estoy usando JavaFX @E.Betanzos

Comment: Sí, pero cómo lo usas? O sea, las bibliotecas de JavaFX cómo las agregas a tu aplicación?

Comment: Uso los jar de javafx, los agregué a la classpath en netbeans.

Comment: Puedes compartir cómo lo haces? Lo que ocurre es que no se están encontrando las bibliotecas nativas de JavaFX y por eso no pueden visualizar los componentes visuales.

Comment: Ya actualicé mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que no se están encontrando la bibliotecas nativas de JavaFX correspondientes a la plataforma de ejecución (ej. para Windows las dll).

Esto pasa porque los JARs que estas usando no incluyen dichas bibliotecas. No se de donde hayas descargado los que estás usando, pero los oficiales son publicados en el repositorio central de Maven. Esto quiere decir que la mejor opción es usar Maven en tu proyecto, pero si no lo haces debes asegurarte de descargar los JARs específicos para tu plataforma.

Te explico un poco mejor.

Cada uno de los módulos de JavaFX (constrols, fxml, graphics, etc.) se componen de 4 JARs, uno es el principal (cuyo nombre sería algo como javafx-controls.jar para `javafx.controls`) y los otros 3 son los que contienen las bibliotecas nativas para cada una de las plataformas soportadas (javafx-controls-win.jar, javafx-controls-linux.jar y javafx-controls-mac.jar). Si no agregas estos JARs específicos  a tu proyectos tendrás los problemas que estás teniendo. Esto no pasaría si usaras Maven ya que el POM de cada JAR principal está configurado para que se descargue el JAR específico correspondiente a la plataforma donde estás desarrollando.

En este enlace (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/16/) podrás ver lo que te comento para el módulo `javafx.controls`.